# Automaticly resize images to same width on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Any plugin that always make the pictures resize always same size? lets say always width 500 px and height = 0 or any size

So if I upload pictures with the size smaller than 500px, lets say the picture width is 250 px and then will automatically resize to width 500px.

And  if   I upload pictures with the size bigger than 500px, lets say the picture width is 950 px and then will automatically resize to width 500px.

So basically if I upload any pictures with small size or big size and then will be automatically resize to width 500 px

Answer (score 0):

use [Simple Image Sizes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/)

create one custom size, select crop option

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do it because I am newbie on programming,I just want to use plugin on the wordpress, anyone help?